# Docker - pass env variable to replace Java max memory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile as follows.

```
ENV SPRING_ENV="local"
ENV APP_OPTS "-Xmx8144m"
RUN echo "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/java ${APP_OPTS}  -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar  /apps/demo/demo-fe.jar --spring.config.location=file:///apps/demo/conf/ump.properties  -Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_ENV} &" > /apps/demo/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /apps/demo/entrypoint.sh
```

When I run the dockerfile, I see a file 'entrypoint.sh' with the java command that I specified in the Dockerfile.

But I want to change the java max memory depending on the environment. So I am running like this.

```
docker run  -it <image_id> sh  -e "APP_OPTS=-Xmx9144m" -e "SPRING_ENV=dev"
```

But when I run it, i check the entrypoint.sh, i don't see the environment variables replaced. Am I missing something?

Does it replace only on the fly when I actually run the container?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `$` in `${APP_OPTS}` (i.e., change it to `\${APP_OPTS}`) -- during `docker build`, the variable is getting replaced with the "current" environment variable, which would be whatever is in your `env` output (otherwise null).  Calling `docker run ... -e "APP_OPTS=-Xmx9144m"` won't do anything at this point because `${APP_OPTS}` has been replaced after the image was created.

Otherwise, you could try saving the `entrypoint.sh` file and put it in the same folder as your `Dockerfile` instead of having your `Dockerfile` create it (and use `COPY` instead to put it where you want it).  That way, the `${APP_OPTS}` environment variable won't get replaced during `docker build`

Answer (score 0):

The Dockerfile (and the `RUN` command) are only executed when you build the image. `SPRING_ENV` and `APP_UMPFE_OPTS` are being evaluated only once and during the build.

When you run the image, the `--env=KEY=VALUE` are passed to the shell (!) running the process defined in the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` (which you need but do not have).

You're missing a `FROM ...` statement near the top of the Dockerfile too.

You will need to define (recommend the shell-form of) `ENTRYPOINT` that invokes the java runtime, passes the environment variables and runs your code, perhaps (have not tried this):

```
FROM ???
ENV SPRING_ENV="local"
ENV APP_OPTS "-Xmx8144m"
ENTRYPOINT /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/java ${APP_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /apps/demo/demo-fe.jar --spring.config.location=file:///apps/demo/conf/ump.properties -Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_ENV}
```

Example:

```
FROM busybox
ENV DOG=Freddie
ENTRYPOINT echo ${DOG}
```

Then:

```bash
docker build --tag=58208029 --file=./Dockerfile .
docker run -it 58208029:latest
Freddie

docker run -it --env=DOG=Henry 58208029:latest
Henry
```

Answer (score 0):

The entrypoint.sh is being written when you build the image, so that `RUN` statement won't be executed again when you run the container. So the entrypoint.sh file itself will not be updated.

Another issue is that when you do the docker run, the -e options need to be before the image name and command:

```
docker run  -it -e "APP_OPTS=-Xmx9144m" -e "SPRING_ENV=dev" <image_id> sh
```

Otherwise those are just being passed as arguments to the entrypoint/command

Also, in your Dockerfile, you probably want single quotes around your entrypoint script so that it doesn't interpolate the values at build time.

```
RUN echo '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/java ${APP_OPTS}  -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar  /apps/demo/demo-fe.jar --spring.config.location=file:///apps/demo/conf/ump.properties  -Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_ENV} &' > /apps/demo/entrypoint.sh
```

Then when you run the container, the entrypoint script should read the variable values at run time from the environment.